# in my code it is reading infinite elements why?

Tags: c

/* c program to find largest subarray whose elements add upto 0
it keep on reading for elements I do not why? for example if i give input
as 4 as number of elements it has to take 4 elements for some elements it
is working fine for some like 1 2 -3 4 it is again asking to enter
elements even after taking 4 elements */

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include<stdlib.h>
    void popout (int a[100], int q, int n,int j) 
    {
        int z; z=n;
        for (int o = q; o < n - 1; o++)
        {
            a[o] = a[o + 1];  //deletes one number
        } 
        int g = j;
        if(g!= 1)
        {
            z--;   //function calls recursively till we are 
                   // deleting only one number 
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {     
                popout(a,a[i],z,g-1); // after deleting one number again 
                                      //again runs a loop to delete other 
                                      //number from already deleted array
            }
            g--;
        }
    } 
        
        
        
    int main () 
    {
        int n;int f;
        int a[100];
        int b[100];
        printf ("enter number of elemnts");
        scanf ("%d",&n);
        printf ("enter elements");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            scanf ("%d", &a[i]);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            b[i] = a[i];
        for (int j = 1; j < n; j++)
            a[0] = a[0] + a[j];
        if (a[0] == 0)
            printf ("%d", n);
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            a[i] = b[i];
        /* pop out number by number */ 
        for(int p = 1;p < n; p++) {  //p:number of elements to be deleted at onece
            for(int i=0;i<n;i++) {  
                popout(a,a[i],n,p);
                for(int g=1;g<n-1;g++) {
                    a[0]+=a[g];
                }
                if(a[0]==0)
                {
                    printf("%d",n-p); exit(0);
                }
                else {
                    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
                    a[i]=b[i];
                }
            }
        }
        return 0;    
    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to indent your code properly. Indentation is important for readability. Note: If your problem happens before you even reach the `for` loop, then the loop and all code that was not executed at that time, is not relevant for the question. Code not relevant should be removed when a mimimum example is created.

Comment: `exit` does nothing, you need `exit(/*exit_code*/)`

Comment: @anastaciu even that is not working i have written exit(0); instead of exit; but no use...

Comment: @SrujithChaithanya I didn't expected it to, it's just an aside, that's why it's a comment and not an answer, mind [Gerhardh comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67001898/in-my-code-it-is-reading-infinite-elements-why?noredirect=1#comment118433643_67001898).

Comment: You should never use `scanf` or other I/O functions without checking return value. Are you sure, `n` is read in properly?

Comment: When calling popout second parameter is a[i] : should not it be i ?

Comment: SO works better if you provide feedback to suggestions and questions in comments.